# Segmentation fault in reversing string program

Tags: c++, string, reverse

I am trying to reverse a string. Can someone explain me why this is giving me segmentation fault?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  string str,rstr;
  int len=str.length(),i=0;
  cin>>str;
  while(str[i]!='\0'){
    rstr[--len]=str[i++];
  }
  rstr[str.length()]='\0';
  cout<<rstr;
  return 0;
}
```

P.S.: Need to reverse it without using library functions.

Comment: `rstr` is empty.  You can't use `[]` on elements that don't exist.

Comment: rstr[--len] that is an invalid location. Allocate storage for rstr upfront

Comment: Use `std::reverse()` instead.

Comment: You should get into the habbit of debugging your code, that would have shown you what the values of `str`,`rstr` and `len` are (and why this causes your "segmentation fault")

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz That still doesn't work.  You have to make the `size()` big enough which requires `resize()`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks Nathan for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go the way you are doing it, for practice purposes, try this changes and start from there

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  string str,rstr;
  cin>>str;                  // --- Moved this line up
  rstr = str;                // --- Added this line
  int len=str.length(),i=0;
  while(str[i]!='\0'){
   rstr[--len]=str[i++];
  }
  rstr[str.length()]='\0';
  cout<<rstr;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just use reverse iterator

```
std::string s = "Hello";
std::string r(s.rbegin(), s.rend());
```

Comment: Links to other methods for reversing strings. Seems to be many options but all roads lead to Rome https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199241/reversing-a-string-in-c-using-a-reverse-iterator?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

`str` is nothing but a declared string here:

```
  int len=str.length(),i=0;
```

So you can't do `str.length()`

Do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  string str,rstr;
  int len,i=0;
  cin>>str;
  len = str.length();
  while(str[i]!='\0'){
   rstr[i++]=str[--len];
  }
  rstr[str.length()]='\0';
  cout<<rstr;
  return 0;
}
```